# How to Get Coordinates of All New Created Polygons In Map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to grab all New Created Polygons' Coordinates at [This Google Map Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/p5mJw/3/)
 by Clicking on the `Coordinates` btn as:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'polygoncomplete', function (polygon) {
        coordinates = (polygon.getPath().getArray());
        console.log(coordinates);
      });

function getCoordinates() {
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "Polygon No # -" +coordinates;}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('CoordsButton'), 'click', getCoordinates);
});
```

but as you can see the code only returns the newly completed polygon's coordinates. Can you please let me know how I can get coordinates for all created polygons from starting the Drawing to create a polygon(Since Clicks on [image] button) till to Clicks on `Coordinates` button?

Is there any way I can associate number for each created Polygon? Like `Polygon No1 {..`

---

### Update

---

I declared a global array as:

> ```
> var newpolygons =[];
> ```

and update the code as:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'polygoncomplete', function (polygon) {
  coordinates = (polygon.getPath().getArray());
  console.log(coordinates);
  newpolygons.push(coordinates);
 });
```

now can you please let me know how I can retrieve them?

Comment: One option would be to push the polygons on a global array, iterate through that array to get all the coordinates.

Comment: Hi geocodeZip, thanks for reply but can you please give me an hint how to do that?

Comment: [example that does what you want](http://www.geocodezip.com/blitz-gmap-editor/test5.html) (probably more complicated than you need)

Comment: Exactly this is very complicated . I guess there are lots of functions which I am not gonna use them!

Comment: @geocodezip can you please take a look at my updated post? I generate a  global array but I am not sure if it is right?

Comment: You know what , don't worry I figure it out. Thanks for your hint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok , Thanks to geocodezip here is the solution which worked for me! I am not sure if it is correct!

```
var newpolygons =[];
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'polygoncomplete', function (polygon) {
  coordinates = (polygon.getPath().getArray());
  newpolygons.push(coordinates);
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to push to another array since what you get from api is an array

```
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'polygoncomplete', function (polygon) {

coordinates = (polygon.getPath().getArray());
console.log(coordinates);

for (var i = 0; i < coordinates.length; i++) { 
lat = coordinates[i].lat(); 
lng = coordinates[i].lng(); 

console.log(lat);
console.log(lng);

}

});
```